# Analysis. Easy recurrence relation question

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck on part (i). I have proved hint in the question. I can see that $x - x^2$ bit of the hint somehow relates to $a_{n+1} = a_n ( 1 - a_n)$ as they are of the same form but cannot work out how to use it... Any tips on how to approach this will be appreciated! I feel like I'm missing something so obvious.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a_n < 1/(n+1)$, then applying the hint we have $a_{n+1} < n/(n+1)^2$. Can you show that $n/(n+1)^2<1/(n+2)$?

Comment: That's what I've missed! Cheers.